# Data type conversion error in stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

May someone please help me to resolve this error.

Table structure:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (MYDATE DATETIME2)


INSERT @TABLE
    SELECT 2016-08-08 10:27:58.0000000 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2016-09-25 16:55:00.0000000 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2016-01-07 10:09:00.0000000 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2016-01-07 10:10:00.0000000 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2016-02-26 16:55:00.0000000
```

I don't have permission to alter this table's structure.

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CHECKS 
    @MYDATE DATETIME 
AS
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM       
        TABLE1 t1
    INNER JOIN 
        TABLE2 t2 
    WHERE 
        CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @MYDATE, 105) = MYDATE
```

But client want to pass date parameter like

```
EXEC dbo.ComparePrices '25092016'
```

While doing so getting error like

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ComparePrices, Line 0
>   Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you converting a datetime parameter to varchar(max)???? And what is @DTFETCH? You should keep the datatype as dates and just do the comparison.

Comment: @SeanLange: i am sorry, there was typo error, corrected now

Comment: @AlexK.:  i am sorry, there was typo error, corrected now

Comment: `convert(nvarchar(MAX)` converts to a `VARCHAR` not a `DATETIME`

Comment: My Problem is user want to supply value like string for ex : 08082016 as date. any suggestion please

Comment: Your actual question seems to be: *How can I convert a value like `08082016` into a datetime?* In this case please provide an example with a day higher than 12 as your example could be ddmmyyyy as well as mmddyyyy.

Comment: @Shnugo: user always supply value as ddmmyyyy. Thanks Shnugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `STUFF()` to insert delimiters into the rigth positions. Then you can use `CONVERT()` with the appropriate format. In this case I insert `/` to get the [format `103`. Find details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
DECLARE @stringdate VARCHAR(100)='30092016';
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(@stringdate,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/'),103)
```

### EDIT: With SQL Server < 2008 you can reach the same without `STUFF()`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT(@stringdate,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@stringdate,3,2)+'/'+RIGHT(@stringdate,4),103)
```

### UPDATE

In your comment you ask, how one could do this as `table valued function`. Try something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CHECKS
( 
    @DateAsUnseparatedString_DDMMYYYY VARCHAR(8) 
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM       
        TABLE1 t1
    INNER JOIN 
        TABLE2 t2 ON (1=1)
    WHERE 
        CAST(MYDATE AS DATE)=CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(@DateAsUnseparatedString_DDMMYYYY,3,0,'/'),6,0,'/'),103);
GO
```

And call it like

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.CHECKS('26092016');
```

#### The reason why you get nothing back

... is - quite sure - that you forget about the time portion. A value like `2016-08-08 10:27:58.0000000` **is not equal to** a converted date DDMMYYYY like `08082016`. That's why I use `CAST(... AS DATE)` to get a *naked* date which you can compare against the converted value, which is a naked date too.

Another approach was to use

```
WHERE MYDATE >= TheConvertedValue AND MYDATE < TheConvertedValue+1;
```

Comment: STUFF was introduced in sql 2005 so no need to use the string method version unless they are on 2000 or older.

Comment: @RohiniMathur you did your query backwards. You want to convert the parameter to a datetime. If you try to STUFF with your datetime column it will fail.

Comment: @Shnugo:Thanks a lot Shnugo

Comment: @Shnugo: i did the same and sp executed successfully but when i execute SP passing the string return 0. any suggestion please.

Comment: Data in table in format of 2016-08-08 10:27:58.0000000

Comment: @What do you mean with *return 0*? No records? A `NULL`-value. The numeric value 0? How do you call this (From application? In a sql batch?), Do you know, that the return value of a Stored Procedure is `0` by default and is not meant to transport a result but rather an error/success-state? The return value is not the recordset you see, when you execute this in SSMS... Anyway this was much better solved with an `inline table valued function`...

Comment: @SeanLange, Oh yes, I muddled this up. But, according [to this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx), `STUFF()` came up with 2008... Anyway this should work here...

Comment: I know this is a shocker but BOL is wrong. I just ran this on a 2005 installation and other than having to separate the variable declaration from the value it runs perfectly. Abbreviated version number (Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (X64))

Comment: @SeanLange, thx for checking this out :-) Nice to know, but hoping never to work with SQL Server 2005 or below again :-)

Comment: I know what you mean there. We have one production instance stuck in 2005. It has replication that pulls data from our mainframe and the replication piece will not work with anything higher. It will only be a few months and that entire mainframe will be shutdown for good. Everything else is much newer thankfully.

Comment: @Shnugo: yes no record, i am calling it throgh SSRS Report. please help me how can we solve it through inline table valued function. Thank You Very Much Shnugo.

Comment: @RohiniMathur, with pleasure... One more hint: I must admit, that I'd truly fear this approach... The algorithmen will always take the figures as `ddmmyyyy` If this is user's input you cannot be sure, that this will always be correct. If a date is provided in another format this can work but with wrong result (e.g. `11032016` was meant as 3rd of November) or would produce an error (typos, invalid such as `31062016`, ...). It was much better to pass parameters of the proper data type...